# Replacing specific character value is not working

Tags: r

New to R and not sure why the following is not working.

I've got a dataframe with one column tracking whether respondents to our survey have previously attended one of our webinars. The column contains values as "characters". One value in the column is "*This was not my first webinar from CDC, and I’ve ALSO attended at least one of CDC’s in-person seminars*". Another value is "*This was not my first webinar from CDC, BUT I’ve NEVER attended one of CDC’s in-person seminars.*"

I'm using a very simple code to shorten the values:

```
response_master_df[response_master_df=="This was not my first webinar from HCDC, but I've NEVER attended one of HCDC's in-person seminars."] <- "Yes to Past Webinars, No to Past Seminars"

response_master_df[response_master_df=="This was not my first webinar from HCDC, and I’ve ALSO attended at least one of HCDC’s in-person seminars."] <- "Yes to Past Webinars, Yes to Past Seminars"
```

I'm unclear on why the first renaming works but the 2nd one doesn't. Any insights would be much appreciated!

Comment: You got to look closely, in the first you have '... but I've ... '  with `'`, but in the second you have `... and I've ...` with a `’`. R does differentiate those and I suspect that's the reason why you can't subset properly. Try changing that.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the quick response. That's a great catch and I've tried changing that. But unfortunately, it's still not working...

Comment: Did you also change the one from `HCDC’s`? I don't know your data; otherwise I suppose that it could only be some typo ..

Comment: Hi Taufi, yes I did and that didn't work either.

Comment: Supply some of your data and then we might be able to help you.